# Using jQuery to add one tag into another tag

Tags: jquery, html, tags

got a quandary i was hoping you kind folks could help me out with...

goal:

Using jQuery, I'm trying to add all the occurrences of:

```
<pre> ... </pre>
```

with:

```
<pre><code> ... </code></pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('pre').wrapInner('<code>');
```

Ref: [wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3zbWL/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('pre').html('<code>'+$('pre').html()+'</code>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .wrapInner()

```
$("pre").wrapInner("<code></code>");
```